# Swift ResearchKit Conditional ORKOrderedTask

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, researchkit

I'm currently working on a medical research app with swift based on ResearchKit, which is an objective-c based framework. I'm trying to create a conditional ORKOrderedTask, like the one at: https://gist.github.com/mattio/9126ecc4f08b9f0497d9
Basically, it says that if the answer to the previous question is yes, then display the next question, if not, skip it. I can find the code for it in objective-c but I'm having trouble converting it to swift.

Comment: Rather paste than link your code here, as links can break in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recently merged `ORKNavigableOrderedTask` provides that exact functionality by means of using `NSPredicates` to check against previous or ongoing task results.

In the [RKNavigableTaskExample repository](https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/RKNavigableTaskExample) you can find a small self-contained example on how to use the class. The example is written in *Objective-C*, but it should be easy to call the same APIs from *Swift*.